# is it normal to have a warnings from browser when using piggyback ssl on heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku

This is just a quick question really for my own peace of mind more than anything.

When accessing an app hosted on Heroku through https://myapp.herokuapp.com I get a warning in Google Chrome and Firefox (but not Safari) along the lines of:

You have requested an encrypted page that contains some unencrypted information. Information that you see or enter on this page could easily be read by a third party.

I don't really want to pay the $20 a month for the SSL-Endpoint addon and was just wondering why these warnings appear and whether there was a way around it/how to find the content that is unencrypted.

I have tried both with and without config.force_ssl = true

Any suggestions? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Any references to http:// ?  I had that with Facebook like plugin etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was an issue with a request from Google maps.

As far as I can remember, they changed their API to allow access over https:// after we began development.

It was simply a case of following the new process that was documented on the Google API page